# Using Codeigniter, how can I prevent a User from accessing a page until they've completed the quiz of the chapter previous?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Apologies for the lengthy question, but I'm having much difficulty in preventing a user from accessing a chapter before completing the quiz of the chapter previous. I'm using the Codeigniter framework in order to build an application which teaches individuals how to program in Java. Here is the code to the function in my Controller which primarily displays the questions:

```
public function quizdisplay()
{
$this->load->model('quizmodel');
//Whatever I get is put into an array called questions
$this->data['questions'] = $this->quizmodel->getQuestions();
$this->load->view('take_variables_quiz', $this->data);
}
```

And once the user takes the quiz & submits his/her results, here is the function which displays results:

```
  public function resultdisplay()
  {
    $this->data['checks'] = array(
      'ques1' => $this->input->post('quizid1'),
      'ques2' => $this->input->post('quizid2'),
      'ques3' => $this->input->post('quizid3'),
      'ques4' => $this->input->post('quizid4'),
    );

      $this->load->model('quizmodel');
      $this->data['results'] = $this->quizmodel->getQuestions();
      $this->load->view('result_display', $this->data);
  }
```

The getQuestions function in my model looks as follows:

class quizmodel extends CI_Model {

```
public function getQuestions()
{
$this->db->select("quizid, variables, varone, vartwo, varthree, varanswer");
$this->db->from("quiz");

//gets data
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();

$num_data_returned = $query->num_rows;

if($num_data_returned < 1){
  echo "There is no data in the database.";
  exit();
}
}
```

The chapter at hand above is titled 'Variables' whereby a view is available with textual information relating to Variables in Java. Once read, the user can take a quiz. My ultimate aim is to ensure that the user cannot access the next section titled 'Control Structures' before he or she completes the quiz on Variables. That being said, here is the code to the function that relates to displaying the variables web page:

```
  public function variables(){
    if ($_SESSION['user_logged'] == FALSE){
      $this->session->set_flashdata("error","Please login 1st to view this page");
      redirect("auth/login");
    }
    $this->load->view('variables');
  }
```

As you can probably gather, I'm quite new to Stackoverflow, therefore I hope I've provided enough information. Of course, before posing this question I've attempted to research for myself, but to no avail. I appreciate any feedback. Thank you.

Comment: You can store previous quiz result in session and check session on page if its pass in session allow access else redirect it to previous quiz page

Comment: You should create manyToMany relation between users and quizzes. After user pass quiz you would insert record related to exact user and exact quizz. Next time when user is logged in you would have records of all quizzes user passed and you could act accordingly. Only users who have passed concrete quiz could go to chapter page. This is how would I think of that problem.